# Ruby on Rails has_many :through destroying more than it should

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, has-many-through, destroy

I am creating an app where there are three main models and relationships between them about which I need to track some properties:

#### schema.rb

```
  create_table "entities", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "label"
    t.string   "img"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "entities", ["name"], name: "index_entities_on_name", unique: true, using: :btree

  create_table "entity_group_relationships", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "entity_id"
    t.integer  "group_id"
    t.integer  "order"
    t.string   "label"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "entity_group_relationships", ["entity_id", "group_id"], name: "index_entity_group_relationships_on_entity_id_and_group_id", unique: true, using: :btree

  create_table "entity_property_relationships", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "entity_id"
    t.integer  "property_id"
    t.integer  "group_id"
    t.integer  "order"
    t.string   "label"
    t.string   "value"
    t.integer  "visibility"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "group_property_relationships", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "group_id"
    t.integer  "property_id"
    t.integer  "order"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "group_property_relationships", ["group_id", "property_id"], name: "index_group_property_relationships_on_group_id_and_property_id", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "group_property_relationships", ["group_id"], name: "index_group_property_relationships_on_group_id", using: :btree
  add_index "group_property_relationships", ["property_id"], name: "index_group_property_relationships_on_property_id", using: :btree

  create_table "groups", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "default_label"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "groups", ["name"], name: "index_groups_on_name", unique: true, using: :btree

  create_table "properties", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "units"
    t.string   "units_short"
    t.string   "default_label"
    t.string   "default_value"
    t.integer  "default_visibility"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "properties", ["name"], name: "index_properties_on_name", unique: true, using: :btree
```

#### Entity.rb

```
class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :entity_property_relationships
  has_many :entity_group_relationships
  has_many :properties, 
    through: :entity_property_relationships, 
    inverse_of: :entities
  has_many :groups, 
    through: :entity_group_relationships, 
    inverse_of: :entities
  validates :name, 
    presence: true
  #rest omitted
end
```

#### Property.rb

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_property_relationships
  has_many :entity_property_relationships
  has_many :entities, 
    through: :entity_property_relationships, 
    inverse_of: :properties
  has_many :groups, 
    through: :group_property_relationships, 
    inverse_of: :properties
  validates :name, presence: true
  #rest omitted
end
```

#### Group.rb

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_property_relationships
  has_many :entity_group_relationships
  has_many :entities, 
    through: :entity_group_relationships, 
    inverse_of: :groups
  has_many :properties, 
    through: :group_property_relationships, 
    inverse_of: :groups
  validates :name, 
    presence: true
  #rest omitted
end
```

#### entity_property_relationship.rb

```
class EntityPropertyRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entity
  belongs_to :property
  validates :entity_id, 
    presence: true
  validates :property_id, 
    presence: true
  validates :order, 
    presence: :true
  #rest omitted
end
```

#### entity_group_relationship.rb

```
class EntityGroupRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entity
  belongs_to :group 
  validates :entity_id, 
    presence: true
  validates :group_id, 
    presence: true
  validates :order, 
    presence: true
  #rest omitted
end
```

#### group_property_relationship.rb

```
class GroupPropertyRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :property
  validates :group_id, 
    presence: true
  validates :property_id, 
    presence: true
  validates :order, 
    presence: true
  #rest omitted
end
```

#### The Problem

The behavior that is happening that I am trying to prevent is when a `property` is deleted, all `EntityPropertyRelationships` that share the same `Entity` and `Group` are also deleted.  This isn't the case for `GroupPropertyRelationships`, nor for `EntityGroupRelationships`, and from everything I can see and understand, these relationships have been set up to behave identically.

I am testing this with rspec, here are some tests.

#### Test 1:

```
  it "should still own non-destroyed properties" do
    @entity = Entity.create!(name: "entity")

    @property1 = Property.create!(name: "property1")
    @property2 = Property.create!(name: "property2")

    @group = Group.create!(name: "group")
    @group.own!(@property1)
    @group.own!(@property2)

    @entity.own!(@group)

    @entity.utilizes?(@property1).should eq(true)
    @entity.utilizes?(@property2).should eq(true)

    @property1.destroy

    @entity.utilizes?(@property1).should eq(false)
    @entity.utilizes?(@property2).should eq(true)

    @group.owns?(@property1).should eq(false)
    @group.owns?(@property2).should eq(true)
  end
```

Test 1 is the test that fails.  The `entity` should still `utilize` the `property` - *`utilizes?()` checks that an `EntityPropertyRelationship` exists between the `entity` and the given `property`*.

#### Test 2

```
  it "should still own non-destroyed groups" do
    @entity = Entity.create!(name: "entity")

    @group1 = Group.create!(name: "group1")
    @group2 = Group.create!(name: "group2")

    @entity.own!(@group1)
    @entity.own!(@group2)

    @entity.owns?(@group1).should eq(true)
    @entity.owns?(@group2).should eq(true)

    @group1.destroy

    @entity.owns?(@group1).should eq(false)
    @entity.owns?(@group2).should eq(true)
  end
```

#### Test 3

```
  it "should still utilize non-destroyed groups' properties" do
    @entity = Entity.create!(name: "entity")

    @group1 = Group.create!(name: "group1")
    @group2 = Group.create!(name: "group2")

    @property1 = Property.create!(name: "property1")
    @property2 = Property.create!(name: "property2")

    @group1.own!(@property1)
    @group2.own!(@property2)

    @entity.own!(@group1)
    @entity.own!(@group2)

    @entity.owns?(@group1).should eq(true)
    @entity.owns?(@group2).should eq(true)
    @entity.utilizes?(@property1).should eq(true)
    @entity.utilizes?(@property2).should eq(true)

    @group1.destroy

    @entity.owns?(@group1).should eq(false)
    @entity.owns?(@group2).should eq(true)
    @entity.utilizes?(@property1).should eq(false)
    @entity.utilizes?(@property2).should eq(true)
  end
```

Test 2 and Test 3 pass fine.  I can not seem to pin down what about these relationships warrants a call to destroy each `EntityPropertyRelationship`, even where `property_id` isn't the id of the property being destroyed initially. Is there something I need to change about the relationships, or is there a way I could prevent this with destroy_callbacks?

Comment: Are you sure all the `EntityPropertyRelationship` records are being deleted in Test 1?

Comment: It doesn't destroy all `EntityPropertyRelationships` (`EPRs`), it destroys all `EPRs` where the `entity_id` and the `group_id` are the same as that of the `EPR` that is associated to the `property` that is being destroyed.  I.E. `entity` has properties `property1` & `property2` via `group1` and `property3` & `property4` via `group2`. If `property1` is destroyed, then the relationships between `entity` & `property1` and `entity` & `property2` will be destroyed, but relationships for `property3` & `property4` remain intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch!  I just found the issue.  I never thought it would be where it was, that's why it took so long to find.  In my `GroupPropertyRelationships`, I had an `after_destroy` that would destroy the `EntityPropertyRelationships` for each of that `Group's` associated `Entities`.  It should just be destroying the `EntityPropertyRelationships` where the `group_id` and the `property_id` are the same as the current `GroupPropertyRelationship` being destroyed.  I replaced the `after_destroy` code for the `GroupPropertyRelationship` with:

```
after_destroy do |r|
  EntityPropertyRelationship.destroy_all group_id: r.group_id, property_id: r.property_id
end
```

That must have been a copy-paste error.